# Change the default firebase storage bucket?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have 1 storage buckets in Google cloud storage. Firebase create a new bucket and it is default in firebase console. I want to change the default bucket and delete the bucket created by firebase. And how can I find for config settings for my bucket in google cloud storage.

This is for default bucket :

```
   var config = {
                apiKey: "xx",
                authDomain: "xx.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://xx.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "xx",
                storageBucket: "xx",
                messagingSenderId: "xx"
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your [Storage browser in the Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser), you will see a list of the storage buckets for your project.

[image]

Copy the name of the bucket you want to use and put it in the `storageBucket` property of the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for answer its working now. But shell I delete the firebase buckets ? And I only use storage why is there databaseURL.

Comment: The Firebase storage bucket is automatically generated when you create a Firebase project. If you don't use it anywhere, it will remain empty and you won't be charged for it.

Comment: No charge no problem :)