# How to change default bucket in firebase storage

Tags: firebase

How to change default bucket in firebase storage?

I want to change the location of the bucket.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the default firebase storage bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112170/change-the-default-firebase-storage-bucket)

Comment: yes, but it's a very old screen, so it's different from the current one.

Comment: The link in my answer that Luke linked still works for me. If you can't get that approach working, can you edit your question to show what you tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: This method seems to be a way to create a bucket and directly specify the bucket in the client. What I want is a way to change the default bucket.